# #href not working using State & Scrollspy in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, portfolio, scrollspy

Upgrading my portfolio in react and having an issue with the href not working for my react app. Here is the NavBar code. Live site is here.
https://cigiportfolio.netlify.app/

I believe that it has to do with the use state in combination with the scrollspy. Maybe I have been looking at it too long to figure out the details

```
import Scrollspy from "react-scrollspy";
import Social from "../SocialTwo";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);

  const changeBackground = () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 80) {
      setNavbar(true);
    } else {
      setNavbar(false);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", changeBackground);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="cigi_topbar">
        <div className={navbar ? "topbar_inner opened" : "topbar_inner"}>
          <div className="logo">
            <NavLink to="/">
              <img src="/img/logo/new/smCTGearonly.png" alt="partners brand" />
            </NavLink>
          </div>
          {/* End logo */}
          <div className="menu">
            <Scrollspy
              className="anchor_nav"
              items={["home", "about", "portfolio", "skills", "contact"]}
              currentClassName="current"
              offset={-200}
            >
              <li>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              
            </Scrollspy>
          </div>
          {/* End menu */}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`react-ui-scrollspy`](https://github.com/pettiboy/react-ui-scrollspy#react-ui-scrollspy)

*Full disclosure: I maintain this package.*

1. In your navigation component

```
<div>
  <p data-to-scrollspy-id="first">Section 1</p>
  <p data-to-scrollspy-id="second">Section 2</p>
</div>
```

2. Wrap the elements you want to spy on in the `<ScrollSpy>` component.

```
import ScrollSpy from "react-ui-scrollspy";

<ScrollSpy>
  <div id="first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut dolores
    veritatis doloremque fugit. Soluta aperiam atque inventore deleniti,
    voluptatibus non fuga eos magni natus vel, rerum excepturi expedita.
    Tempore, vero!
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut dolores
    veritatis doloremque fugit. Soluta aperiam atque inventore deleniti,
    voluptatibus non fuga eos magni natus vel, rerum excepturi expedita.
    Tempore, vero!
  </div>
</ScrollSpy>
```

3. Write styles for when the navigation element which is active in your `index.css`

```css
.active-scroll-spy {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```